# 'is_author()' logic in widget for author only

Tags: widgets

So, I have a widget that I only want to show it to the page author.

I used the following logic: is_author()

However it does not seem to work (it shows non-author)

Am I using this logic right?

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please post the code you've tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is_author() is only for Archive pages. 
Quote from the Codex:

> is_author() checks if an Author archive page is being displayed

So viewing a single Post or Page isn't going to get a TRUE from is_author().

I think you'll want something more like this:

```
global $post,$current_user; // get the global variables to check
get_currentuserinfo();  // get current user info
// Now check if the author of this post is the same as the current logged in user
if ($post->post_author == $current_user->ID) {
   // do code here
}
```

I hope this helps. :)

EDIT #1:
Shortened code version.

```
// Check if the author of this post is the same as the current logged in user
if ( $post->post_author == get_current_user_id() ) {
   // do code here
}
```

Comment: +1 for the explaination of why `is_author()` will not work. However, can you not replace `$current_user->ID` with `get_current_user_id()`? That way you can also do away with the `$current_user` global and the call to `get_currentuserinfo()`.

Comment: In fact, if this code is in a template, as opposed to inside a function, I don't think you'd even need the `$post` global.

Comment: Correct. IF it is in a template you can pair it down.
It wasn't clear where this will go, although it'll be some widget area, so I'm not sure what's best for them. I will update my answer with a shortened version too. Thanks for the +1 and the suggestions.

Comment: True, it's often difficult when they don't give you all of the information!

Comment: Thank you for the lovely reply guys. So, I am actually using a plugin called "Widget Logic" which allows me to put logics directly into the individual widget. https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/   In this case, how should I do it?

Comment: Got it working with the following code:  
global $post,$current_user; 
get_currentuserinfo();  
return ($post->post_author == $current_user->ID);

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$obj = get_queried_object();
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

// check if page's post author is same as logged in user
if (isset($obj->post_author) && $obj->post_author == $user_id) {
    // ... do your stuff here
}
```

With `get_queried_object` function you get object of the current page. As it's requested that page should be of "page" type you'll get WP_Post object of the current page (post_type = 'page').

The `get_current_user_id` is self-explanatory.

So if both match, you'll get code running for current user which is creator of the page.

You can also place a check that queried object is 'page':

```
if ($obj instanceof WP_Post && $obj->post_type == 'page') {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You don't need to pass the values through `intval()` if you are using `==` - that only compares values, not types.

Comment: You can use type cast (int) also, all the same. If you want to make 100% sure.

Comment: Thank you for the lovely reply guys. So, I am actually using a plugin called "Widget Logic" which allows me to put logics directly into the individual widget. https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/   In this case, how should I do it?